# How to pass argument to dynamic module?

Tags: powershell, closures, powershell-3.0

I am trying to pass argument to New-module via another function parameters. 
But it doesn't work.

```
function new-remotenode
{
    param
    (
        $hostName,
        $UserName,
        $Password,
        $UniqueName
    )
    New-Module -ArgumentList @($hostName,$UserName,$Password) -Name $UniqueName {

    $HostName = $hostName
    $UserName = $UserName
    $Password = $Password 
    function remoteExec
        { 
          param ( 
            $ScriptBlock
        )
            "Running the command $Scriptblock in " + $Script:HostName + "With " + $Script:UserName + $Script:Password
            #. $ScriptBlock
        }
    } | Import-Module -PassThru
}

function Remove-remotenode
{
    param
    (
        $name
    )
    Remove-module $name
}

$remoteNode = New-RemoteNode -hostName "<Some ip address>" -UserName "Admin" -Password "Password1" -uniqueName "Node1"

remoteExec { Get-childitem }
```

I am passing Username, Password and hostname but i am not able to access them inside remoteExec function. The result displays as below without UserName, Password and hostname

> Running the command  Get-childitem  in With

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the parameters in the Module scriptblock:

```
New-Module -ArgumentList @($hostName,$UserName,$Password) -Name $UniqueName {
    param(
        $HostName,
        $UserName,
        $Password
    )

    function remoteExec
    { 
        param ( 
            $ScriptBlock
        )
        "Running the command $Scriptblock in " + $Script:HostName + "With " + $Script:UserName + $Script:Password
        #. $ScriptBlock
    }
} | Import-Module -PassThru
```

Comment: I have edited my question bit. Seems arguments to New-module is not passed inside.

Comment: @Samselvaprabu Have you tested my code? I can't reproduce the error you describe (ie. I can pass arguments to my module scriptblock just fine, using `-ArgumentList`)

Comment: I replaced it with your piece of code it works. What is different. I have almost written the same .

Comment: Look closely at my example - I declare a `param()` block inside the `New-Module` scriptblock

Comment: Thank you for your help. It helped me a lot in my work.